# Apex web service works in Workbench, but tests fail

Tags: apex, unit-test, webservices, trailhead

I'm trying to complete the [Apex Web Services Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/force_com_dev_intermediate/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_webservices), but am having some difficulties.

The code I've written appears to function correctly when I access it via Workbench, but I can't persuade my unit tests to pass.

My SUT class is like this:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Accounts/*/contacts')
global class AccountManager {
    @HttpGet
    global static Account getAccount()
    {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;

        String accId = req.requestURI.substringBetween('Accounts/', '/contacts');

        system.debug(accId);

        return getAccountById(accId);
    }

    public static Account getAccountById(string account_id)
    {
        Account acc = [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) 
                       FROM Account WHERE Id = :account_id];

        return acc;
    }
}
```

When I call this via Workbench, the response looks sane:

[image: Screenshot of Workbench]

My test looks like this:

```
@isTest static void TestGetAccountById() {
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
    request.requestUri = 'https://playful-raccoon-288300-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Accounts/0011r00001nUpkgAAC/contacts';
    request.httpMethod = 'GET';
    RestContext.request = request;
    // Call the method to test
    Account thisAcc = AccountManager.getAccount();

    system.debug('here');
    // Verify results
    System.assert(thisAcc != null);
    System.assertEquals('Bluebeards Grog House', thisAcc.Name);
}
```

The exception I'm getting is:

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

I understand from my research that this means that the query is returning 0 rows. This confuses me because the account ID being passed is the same as the one I'm using in Workbench. I wondered if my logic for extracting the account ID was wonky, but I've been able to verify this using checkpoints.

Am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: This is a dupe. Sorry! I did search, but didn't find the other question. The accepted answer on it solved my issue though, so thanks!

Comment: Admittedly, it's pretty hard to find, but it has been asked a few times. Glad I could help you out!